# Using Group By And Over clause on Different columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this;

```
col 1|col 2|col 3
a    | 2   | 10
b    | -1  | 10
a    | 10  | 10
```

The goal is to get output as;

```
col 1|  col 2| col 3
a    | 12    | 30
b    |  -1   |30
```

I tried the following query;

```
select col 1,
sum(col 2),
sum(col 3) OVER()
From table t1
group by col 1
```

But I got the error; col 3 is not a valid group by expression.
Kindly suggest an alternate solution.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try taking the sum of `SUM(col3)` over the entire table:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    SUM(col2),
    SUM(SUM(col3)) OVER()
FROM table t1
GROUP BY col1;
```

If you want to use `SUM` as a window function, then you need to sum something which is available *after* `GROUP BY` has evaluated.  `SUM(col3)` is available, while `col3` is not.

Comment: Thanks for your help.it works great. But this soln. adds repeated values of col 3.  if we want to choose distinct value of `col 3`(see edits) is their a way to get the output as 20 in col 3. Please see the edits in the question.